# Cannot change image height in Firefox when loading image from css

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a very simple img that is loaded from css. The image has a height of 300px, and I am trying to stretch it vertically to 700px:

```
<div>
    <img class="test">
</div>
```

Currently I have it as:

```
.test:after {
    min-height:700px;
    height:700px;
    content: url('/test.png');
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome. In Firefox, the image does not stretch; it keeps its original height and there is a big block of empty space below it. So I replace `content: url(...)` with `background-image: url(...)` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`. But still the same result.

Why is Firefox not stretching my image vertically in either case? How do I stretch my image?

Also, I know I can use `src` but I want to load it from css and without any javascript.

Comment: I'm still really interested how you've seen it *perfectly work* in Chrome... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/
>
> ### Image

```
div::before {
  content: url(image.jpg);
}
```

> This is literally an image on the page like  would be. It could
>   also be a gradient. **Note that you cannot change the dimensions of the
>   image when inserted this way.**

But just at this point they're offering the solution:

> **You could also insert an image by using an empty string an empty string for the content, making it display: block in some way, sizing
>   it, and using background-image. That way you could re-size it with
>   background-size.**

Comment: I actually haven't, but the quoted stuff should apply equally to that case.

Comment: "That way you could re-size it with background-size."